# Why is string modified in C even when I'm not trying to modify it?

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, kernighan-and-ritchie, function-definition

I'm trying to solve exercise 1-19 in K&R C second edition. "Write a function reverse that reverses the character string s. Use it to write program that reverses its input a line at a time."

My solution takes two input strings `s` and `t`. `s` is source and `t` is target. And it copies the data in source `s` to `t`. I'm able to solve the problem, but I'm struggling hard to understand why would source string `s` be modified, even though it is not on the left hand side of the equal operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Solution to Exercise 1-19. Chapter 1 */

#define MAXLENGTH 10

int getln(char s[], int lim);
void reverse(char s[], char t[]);

int main()
{
  int i, len;

  char s[MAXLENGTH]; /* original string */
  char t[MAXLENGTH]; /* reversed string */

  while ((len = getln(s, MAXLENGTH)) > 0) {
    printf("before reverse: %s", s);
    reverse(s,t);
    printf("reversed string: %s\n", t);
    printf("after reverse: %s", s);
  }  
  return 0; 
}

/* getln: read a line into s, return length */
int getln(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c, i, l; 

  l = 0; 
  for (i = 0; ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n'); ++i) {
    if (i < (lim - 1)) {
      s[l] = c; 
      ++l;
    }  
  }  

  if (c == '\n') {
    s[l] = c; 
    ++l;
  }  

  s[l] = '\0';
  return l; 
}

/* reverse: reverses s to target t */
void reverse(char s[], char t[])
{
  int i, j; 
  for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
   ;  
  --i;                                                                                                                                                                             
  if (s[i] == '\n') {
    --i;
  }  
  for (j = 0; i >= 0; ++j) {
    t[j] = s[i];
    --i;
  }  
  t[j] = '\0';
}
```

Test case:

```
$ ./a.out < testdata 
before reverse: abcdefghi
reversed string: ihgfedcba
after reverse: abcdefghi
ihgfedcba$
```

Contents of file testdata:

```
$ cat testdata 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
$
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the function `getln` To simplify the analyze of the function let's assume that `lim` is equal to 2.

Then in this loop

```
  l = 0; 
  for (i = 0; ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n'); ++i) {
    if (i < (lim - 1)) {
      s[l] = c; 
      ++l;
    }  
  }
```

you can write `lim-1` characters that is only one character. The loop stops its iterations when the user will press the key Enter that sends to the input buffer the new line character `'\n'`.

So the last read character is the new line character `'\n'`. This character is stored in the string after the loop

```
  if (c == '\n') {
    s[l] = c; 
    ++l;
  }
```

Now the limit is exhausted. Two characters of the passed character array are set.

However in the next statement

```
  s[l] = '\0';
```

there is access to the memory beyond the limit when `l` is equal to 2.

That is all. The function invokes undefined behavior provided that the value of the parameter `lim` is equal to the size of the passed character array. The terminating zero character `'\0'` is written in the memory outside the character array and later can be overwritten.

I would define the function the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t getln( char s[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    if ( n )
    {
        int c;

        while ( i + 1 < n && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
        {
            s[i++] = c;
        }

        if ( c == '\n' && i + 1 < n ) s[i++] = c;

        s[i] = '\0';
    }       

    return i;   
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char s[N];

    while ( getln( s, N ) ) printf( "\"%s\"\n", s );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

then the program output will be

```
"abcdefghi"
"jklmnopqr"
"stuvwxyz
"
```

That is only the last entered string contains the new line characters.

Pay attention to that in the exercise there is written

> Write a function reverse that reverses the character string s.

This means that you need to reverse the original string itself instead of coping it in the reverse order to another character array.

Such a function can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] != '\0' ) n++;

    if ( n && s[n-1] == '\n' ) --n;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

size_t getln( char s[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    if ( n )
    {
        int c;

        while ( i + 1 < n && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
        {
            s[i++] = c;
        }

        if ( c == '\n' && i + 1 < n ) s[i++] = c;

        s[i] = '\0';
    }       

    return i;   
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char s[N];

    while ( getln( s, N ) ) printf( "\"%s\"\n", reverse( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Again if the input is

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

then the program output is

```
"ihgfedcba"
"rqponmlkj"
"zyxwvuts
"
```

If you want to remove the new line character `'\n'` from the string inside the function `reverse` then substitute this statement

```
    if ( n && s[n-1] == '\n' ) --n;
```

for this one

```
    if ( n && s[n-1] == '\n' ) s[--n] = '\0';
```

Comment: May be I'm getting this wrong. But if `getln` had a bug, String `s` shouldn't have printed correctly before the function `reverse` is called. It prints correctly before `reverse` is called. And then is modified post `reverse`.

Comment: @NachiketChinchure The zero-terminating character is stored outside the character array s (it seems it is placed in the array t). After the call of the  function reveres this zero terminating character is overwritten.

Comment: @NachiketChinchure This output "after reverse: abcdefghi
ihgfedcba"  shows that the zero terminating character was not found in the array s.:)

Answer (score -1):

You are not allocating memory for `c` or `t`, therefore you are overwriting things.